# Squid proxy bandwidth hogging prevention

Tags: networking, proxy, bandwidth, squid

I have a squid proxy acting as a parental filter on our LAN, however it's very easy for one users downloading to slow everyone else down. My question is: Is it possible to set up something that achieves the following:

*NB: Where I have referred to "users" I am referring to devices as I do not have any login system. My internet speed is assumed to be 10Mbps exactly.*

1) When several users are browsing Wikipedia the burst downloads required, assuming the bursts occur 1 at a time, each burst gets the full internet bandwidth of ~10Mbps

2) When 2 or more users are downloading files the internet bandwidth gets divided equally i.e. each user gets 5Mbps when there are 2 concurrent large downloads and each user gets 3.33Mbps when there are 3 concurrent large downloads

3) When there are 2 concurrent large downloads occurring and third user wants to browse Wikipedia the burst downloads for Wikipedia momentarily change the bandwidth allocations so that while the Wikipedia page is download each user gets 3.33Mbps and once the page is downloaded the two large downloads get back their 5Mbps each

**Many thanks for your help it is greatly appreciated**

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into [CoovaChilli](http://coova.org/CoovaChilli). While its most common use-cases involve things such as user login, RADIUS calls, and other things pertaining to managing users, it is easy to set up one that defaults to allowing everything without logging in, and just use it for load balancing.

With it you can set up bandwidth limitations and upload/download quotas, which should solve your issue.

Once up and running, it's just a matter of two lines in the config file to also include an existing squid proxy in the mix.

Comment: This is almost perfect, but I failed to mention (sorry) that this is running on a raspberry pi which only has 1 ethernet port and unfortunately it has been deemed that this is not worth any extra monetary investment. _(CoovaChilli aparently relies on two physically seperate NICs)_